# How do I name a list item from a variable in R?

Tags: r

I've seen other similar questions, but not really specific enough to my case for me to make the connection.

I'm trying to have a list of objects so I can make my program somewhat modular. They're supposed to be based on state name, as in the following code:

```
statedata <- list()
for (i in state.name){
   date <- somedates # vector from a dataframe
   statedata <- c(statedata,list(i=dates))
}
```

however, what I end up with is:

> > names(statedata)
>   [1] "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i"
>   [29] "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i" "i"

Is there a way to give each vector in the list a name from a variable?

Comment: from the title I wonder if there is a reason not to use  `names<-`; from the post I don't understand what you're trying to do and ask.

Comment: `statedata <- c(statedata, setNames(list(dates), i))`, perhaps.

Comment: Sorry about that. `names(i)` returns the `NULL` value. What I'm trying to do is create a list where each state name points to a vector. So down the line I could parse back through the list and retrieve the values.

Comment: @KotaMori that was it, thank you